# Windows command line alternative for "export"

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

I've bought a book about Machine Learning, and it needs an environment setup. The code in the book is

```
$ export ML_PATH="$HOME/ml"
$ mkdir -p $ML_PATH
```

but as far as I know, this are Linux/UNIX commands, so there are alternatives for Windows?

Comment: Some sort of equivalent in Windows are environmental variables but you can't just think it's 100% compatibile. You should follow instructions specified for Windows

Comment: It's a fair question, but as @muminers already indicates, Windows is sufficiently different enough to cause more problems. For example, that next line; see [What is equivalent to Linux mkdir -p in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/905226/2564301).

Comment: This isn't really a Python question *or* a machine-learning question (or even a programming question); it's purely about Windows, and probably a better fit for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). That said, if your book only documents setup steps for Linux, maybe you should use a Linux VM? You're going to hit more issues later.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: ah - the *tags* :) Let me help OP out with that. But otherwise it seems heavily programming-related.

Comment: i've already downloaded the tensor flow environment and other things requested, but i don't know how to set that env. variable. I have a Linux VM but i have to do the _WHOLE_ process. In case there isn't a way to proceed i'll follow your suggestion

Comment: Google "bash export" for basic hits.  Nothing special, Windows already behaves that way.  So simply use SET.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`set`

(Answers must be 30 chars minimum. Oh yes they must.)

Answer (score 3):

```
SET ML_PATH="$HOME/ml"
SET mkdir $ML_PATH`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please consider including more details in your answer.

Comment: Unlike EXPORT, neither of these variables will survive past the end of the script execution.