# yarn run script with parameters

Tags: bash, hadoop-yarn

How do I pass a parameter? When I run "yarn generate" it will make both a "-p" and a "test" directory. But it works well when I run "mkdir -p test" in bash. I tried to [-p] as well but it only creates that directory.

```
"scripts": {
    "generate": "mkdir -p test"
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I could not reproduce the issue that you mentioned (my config: `node v8.11.1` and `yarn v1.2.1`, latest MacOS), according to the [yarn docs](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run#toc-yarn-run-script), you can pass the arguments to `yarn` script by appending them normally, like so:

```
yarn generate -p test
```

In this case your npm (yarn) scripts config (in the `package.json`, I assume) would look like

```
"scripts": {
    "generate": "mkdir"
}
```

If you're using Windows, you indeed won't have the `mkdir -p` flag (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905226/what-is-equivalent-to-linux-mkdir-p-in-windows)). In order to make what you want (check if the folder does not exist and if so, create one) you'd need to [use some cmd commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033801/checking-if-a-folder-exists-using-a-bat-file). So your package.json will contain smth like

```
"scripts": { 
    "generate": "IF NOT EXIST test mkdir test" 
}
```

Comment: I run on windows. Yes it's in the package.json and it looks like it does in my question :) I want to create a folder and the parameter -p is for ignore createing the folder if it already exist. But when I run it with yarn it creates both a "test" and a "-p" folder

Comment: Well, then it's a completely different issue, because `-p` is not supported in Windows' `mkdir`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905226/what-is-equivalent-to-linux-mkdir-p-in-windows
And in order to make what you want you'd need to use some cmd commands, like here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033801/checking-if-a-folder-exists-using-a-bat-file
So your `package.json` will contain smth like
`"scripts": { "generate": "IF NOT EXIST test mkdir test" }`

Comment: I'm afraid in order to make it work on mac you'll need another `npm` 
 (`package.json`) script

Comment: it should work with this? "scripts": { 
    "generate-pc": "IF NOT EXIST test mkdir test", 
"generate-mac": "mkdir -p test"}

Comment: yes,looks like it :)
Tested first script on Windows and the second on Mac, they seem to work as expected!

Comment: How do I continue with more commands no matter if the folder exist or not? "IF NOT EXIST test mkdir test; echo test". This doesn't work if the folder exist

Comment: Awesome, simple & best solution.