# How to write powershell syntax in yarn script

Tags: windows, powershell, npm, yarnpkg

I'm trying to slim down the process it takes to rebuild my php/react app, but I'm having trouble with `yarn`/`npm` commands. Is there a way to write a script that reads `Powershell` syntax? Right now I'm just copy pasting it since `yarn` isn't reading it properly.

Example:

`yarn copy` to run `cp -r src/services build/services; cp -r vendor build/vendor`

Comment: Did you check `yarn run` https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/run/ ? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010211/yarn-run-script-with-parameters